Problems adjusting color in tikzpicture
I have the following code.
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{intersections}
  \usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween} 
% PGFPlots Kompatibilitätseinstellung
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \definecolor{customRed2}{HTML}{feb77e}    % Light yellow
        \definecolor{customOrange2}{HTML}{251255} % Light orange
        \definecolor{customBlue2}{HTML}{b73779}
        \begin{axis}[
            width=15cm,
            height=6cm,
            ybar stacked,
            ymin=0,
            ymax=130,
            ylabel=\footnotesize Item,
            xlabel=\footnotesize Day,
            xtick=data,
            enlarge x limits=0.02,
            x tick label style={rotate=0},
            legend style={at={(0.5,-0.25)}, anchor=north, legend columns=3},
            ymajorgrids=true,
            ticklabel style={font=\scriptsize},
            grid style=dashed,
            bar width=0.8,
            nodes near coords,
            every node near coord/.append style={
                font=\tiny,
                text=white,
            },
            every node near coord/.style={
                check for zero/.code={
                    \pgfmathparse{\pgfplotspointmeta<1}
                    \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
                        \pgfkeysalso{/pgf/coordinate}
                    \fi
                },
                check for zero
            }
        ]
        % 
        \addplot[fill=customOrange2] coordinates {
            (1,35) (2,38) (3,42) (4,28) (5,15) (6,22) (7,45) (8,32) (9,18) (10,12)
            (11,55) (12,48) (13,25) (14,20) (15,30) (16,16) (17,28) (18,42) (19,38)
            (20,15) (21,10) (22,44) (23,52) (24,18) (25,32) (26,40) (27,12) (28,35)
            (29,42) (30,28) (31,35)
        };
        \addplot[fill=customBlue2] coordinates {
            (1,42) (2,35) (3,58) (4,65) (5,32) (6,25) (7,15) (8,48) (9,52) (10,45)
            (11,38) (12,22) (13,28) (14,45) (15,50) (16,58) (17,25) (18,40) (19,42)
            (20,85) (21,68) (22,12) (23,32) (24,58) (25,35) (26,48) (27,42) (28,38)
            (29,45) (30,52) (31,48)
        };
        \addplot[fill=customRed2] coordinates {
            (1,18) (2,32) (3,12) (4,15) (5,48) (6,45) (7,25) (8,12) (9,28) (10,32)
            (11,22) (12,45) (13,42) (14,32) (15,28) (16,15) (17,42) (18,15) (19,18)
            (20,12) (21,22) (22,32) (23,18) (24,28) (25,35) (26,15) (27,32) (28,22)
            (29,28) (30,35) (31,32)
        };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

This creates the following image.
I am satisfied so far, but unfortunately I want to make the colour of the numbers in the bars white and change the size to \scriptsize. Unfortunately this does not work. How can I solve this?

Unable to run the code… No problem without the every node near coord/.style={… part (last tikzpicture option)

Your code gives a lot of errors... what is that check for zero supposed to do there? If you remove it and remove the figure floating environment that makes no sense in standalone, your code works (although white over orange is not so readable)

\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{intersections}
  \usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
% PGFPlots Kompatibilitätseinstellung
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \definecolor{customRed2}{HTML}{feb77e}    % Light yellow
    \definecolor{customOrange2}{HTML}{251255} % Light orange
    \definecolor{customBlue2}{HTML}{b73779}
    \begin{axis}[
        width=15cm,
        height=6cm,
        ybar stacked,
        ymin=0,
        ymax=130,
        ylabel=\footnotesize Item,
        xlabel=\footnotesize Day,
        xtick=data,
        enlarge x limits=0.02,
        x tick label style={rotate=0},
        legend style={at={(0.5,-0.25)}, anchor=north, legend columns=3},
        ymajorgrids=true,
        ticklabel style={font=\scriptsize},
        grid style=dashed,
        bar width=0.8,
        nodes near coords,
        every node near coord/.append style={
            font=\tiny,
            text=white,
        },
    ]
    %
    \addplot[fill=customOrange2] coordinates {
            (1,35) (2,38) (3,42) (4,28) (5,15) (6,22) (7,45) (8,32) (9,18) (10,12)
            (11,55) (12,48) (13,25) (14,20) (15,30) (16,16) (17,28) (18,42) (19,38)
            (20,15) (21,10) (22,44) (23,52) (24,18) (25,32) (26,40) (27,12) (28,35)
            (29,42) (30,28) (31,35)
        };
    \addplot[fill=customBlue2] coordinates {
            (1,42) (2,35) (3,58) (4,65) (5,32) (6,25) (7,15) (8,48) (9,52) (10,45)
            (11,38) (12,22) (13,28) (14,45) (15,50) (16,58) (17,25) (18,40) (19,42)
            (20,85) (21,68) (22,12) (23,32) (24,58) (25,35) (26,48) (27,42) (28,38)
            (29,45) (30,52) (31,48)
        };
    \addplot[fill=customRed2] coordinates {
            (1,18) (2,32) (3,12) (4,15) (5,48) (6,45) (7,25) (8,12) (9,28) (10,32)
            (11,22) (12,45) (13,42) (14,32) (15,28) (16,15) (17,42) (18,15) (19,18)
            (20,12) (21,22) (22,32) (23,18) (24,28) (25,35) (26,15) (27,32) (28,22)
            (29,28) (30,35) (31,32)
        };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

To change the color of the text in just one plot, just repeat the .append style for that plot only --- thanks to the fact that pgfkeys are normally local, it works. For example, you can change the code for the orange bars (color that you call customRed2, while your customOrange2 is really blue ) like this:
[...]
\addplot[fill=customRed2, every node near coord/.append style={text=black,}, ] coordinates {
            (1,18) (2,32) (3,12) (4,15) (5,48) (6,45)
[...]



+1, however, for labels is more correct to write ylabel=Item, xlabel=Day, label style = {font=\footnotesize},, also \pgfplotsloattikztoo,\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` is with now default.

@Zarlo yep, you're right (and there are not-needed libraries too), but I just did the minimum work possible (lazyness!)

@Rmano Thank you for your help. Is it also possible to only make the color in the orange part black and white for the other two?

... as @Zarko commented, better make another question for this.

@marvelfab12,   it seem that now is time to consider to accept answer (by clicking on check mark at top left side of answers) which (on the best way according to your expectation) solve your problem. As I see, so far you not accept anyone you received on your questions. Are no one fulfill your expectation?

@marvelfab12 It results it's easier than I though, so I added it on this answer...

Thank you very much!

To long for a comment ... Mostly contain off-topic suggestion. It is based on nice @Rmano answer, so all credits lets go to it.
As follows from @Rmano answer, your problem can be solved by the following code lines in axis preamble:
every node near coord/.append style={font=\tiny, text=white},

Your document that should show your problem unfortunately is not MWE (Minimal Working Example) nor can be compiled. A lot to problem unrelated code contain lot of errors and such it only distract people which may be interested to solve your problem.
IN effort to make an MWE from your example I first cleared it to the part of code which is essential to the your problem. All other I was consider as clutter and removed it.
At diagram style definition I suggest to use a way as is described in pgfplots package documentation. Beside this, to diagram I add a legend since you define its style in axis options.
An example of MWE can be:
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
% colors let be defined globally
    \definecolor{customRed2}{HTML}{feb77e}    % Light yellow
    \definecolor{customOrange2}{HTML}{251255} % Light orange
    \definecolor{customBlue2}{HTML}{b73779}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width=15cm, height=6cm,
        ymajorgrids,
        grid style=dashed,
        axis on top,    % otherwise  grid is not visible
        ybar stacked,
        bar width=0.8,
        ymin=0,
        ymax=130,
        ylabel=Item, xlabel=Day, % changed
        label style = {font=\footnotesize},% added
        xtick=data,
        ticklabel style={font=\scriptsize},
        enlarge x limits=0.02,
        nodes near coords,
        every node near coord/.append style={font=\tiny, text=white },  % solve your problem
        legend style={at={(0.5,-0.25)}, font=\footnotesize, anchor=north, legend columns=3},
        /tikz/every even column/.append style = {column sep=1em},       % added, if you liked
    ]
    %
    \addplot[fill=customOrange2] coordinates {
            (1,35) (2,38) (3,42) (4,28) (5,15) (6,22) (7,45) (8,32) (9,18) (10,12)
            (11,55) (12,48) (13,25) (14,20) (15,30) (16,16) (17,28) (18,42) (19,38)
            (20,15) (21,10) (22,44) (23,52) (24,18) (25,32) (26,40) (27,12) (28,35)
            (29,42) (30,28) (31,35)
        };
    \addplot[fill=customBlue2] coordinates {
            (1,42) (2,35) (3,58) (4,65) (5,32) (6,25) (7,15) (8,48) (9,52) (10,45)
            (11,38) (12,22) (13,28) (14,45) (15,50) (16,58) (17,25) (18,40) (19,42)
            (20,85) (21,68) (22,12) (23,32) (24,58) (25,35) (26,48) (27,42) (28,38)
            (29,45) (30,52) (31,48)
        };
    \addplot[fill=customRed2] coordinates {
            (1,18) (2,32) (3,12) (4,15) (5,48) (6,45) (7,25) (8,12) (9,28) (10,32)
            (11,22) (12,45) (13,42) (14,32) (15,28) (16,15) (17,42) (18,15) (19,18)
            (20,12) (21,22) (22,32) (23,18) (24,28) (25,35) (26,15) (27,32) (28,22)
            (29,28) (30,35) (31,32)
        };
    \legend{ task 1, task 2, task 3}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


If you like to solve some other issues in your document example, please ask new question in which you consider proposed solution  from answers to this question.

@Rmano - Zarko Very nice answers and already positively rated. My best regards.

@Sebastiano, thank you very much!
